# google-cloud-resource-manage list projects 403 The caller does not have permission

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-cloud-resource-manager

I created a GCP service account and assigned the needed permissions for listing the projects inside the organization. When I'm using the `gcloud cli`, everything works:

```sh
gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file=./key.json
gcloud projects list

# -> List of all projects
```

But when I try the "same" with the [Python Client for Google Cloud Resource Manager](https://github.com/googleapis/python-resource-manager), I receive a `403 The caller does not have permission` error message.

```py
# pip install google-cloud-resource-manager==1.4.1
from google.oauth2 import service_account
from google.cloud import resourcemanager_v3

# Load gcp credentials
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file('./key.json')

# Create resourcemanager_v3 ProjectsClient
resourcemanager_v3_projects_client = resourcemanager_v3.ProjectsClient(credentials=credentials)

# Initialize request argument(s)
list_projects_request = resourcemanager_v3.ListProjectsRequest(show_deleted=False, parent='')

# Make the request
page_result = resourcemanager_v3_projects_client.list_projects(request=list_projects_request)


# -> Error...
# -> grpc_helpers.py", line 68, in error_remapped_callable
# -> raise exceptions.from_grpc_error(exc) from exc
# -> google.api_core.exceptions.PermissionDenied: 403 The caller does not have permission
```

Does the `Python Client for Google Cloud Resource Manager` needs some other permission than the `gcloud cli` or do I miss something inside the Python code?

Comment: This might be related to this [github issue](https://github.com/googleapis/python-resource-manager/issues/148) with a bug case.

Comment: Thank you, @AlexG. After reviewing the provided issue and the related links, I saw, that I missed the `parent` argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems I missed the `parent` [parameter](https://github.com/googleapis/python-resource-manager/blob/cc343e906d3d7edbecb1cd0bb04cc547db273b1a/google/cloud/resourcemanager_v3/types/projects.py#L189)... 
The following snipped should list the projects of a specific folder or organization.

```py
# pip install google-cloud-resource-manager==1.4.1
from google.oauth2 import service_account
from google.cloud import resourcemanager_v3

# Load gcp credentials
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file('./key.json')

# Create resourcemanager_v3 ProjectsClient
resourcemanager_v3_projects_client = resourcemanager_v3.ProjectsClient(credentials=credentials)

# Initialize request argument(s)
list_projects_request = resourcemanager_v3.ListProjectsRequest(show_deleted=False, parent='folders/%folder-id%') # for organization: 'organizations/%organization-id%'

# Make the request
page_result = resourcemanager_v3_projects_client.list_projects(request=list_projects_request)

# Handle the response
for response in page_result:
    print(response)
```

Comment: Don't you mean parent='folders/%folder-id%' ?

Comment: @OdedBenDov what do you mean?

Comment: You wrote parent='folders/%project-id%' where I think you meant the folder-id should be speficied after "folders/" (not project-id)